# subprocesses efficiency in python for interpreting

Tags: python, performance, subprocess, pypy

I am here asking about python subprocesses efficiency.

I am trying the create a program which needs to be able to execute other languages code.
For example lets say I need to run js files (so I would use node interpreter)

I am using a simple code (based on a question I have asked before, about Kotlin ProcessBuilder vs python), And I do not understand why why calling `py` and calling `cmd` with commandline makes the time difference 10 times much worse

```
import subprocess
from time import perf_counter_ns 

started = 0
completed = 0

def call(): 
    process = subprocess.Popen(["node", "printHello.js"],
                                                stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                                stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                                universal_newlines=True)

    process.wait()


for i in range(0, 1000):
    if (i % 20 == 0):
        print("Turn ", i)
    start = perf_counter_ns()
    call()
    started += (perf_counter_ns() - start)
    completed += (perf_counter_ns() - start)

print("Average time (ms) to start a process: ", started * 1e-9)
print("Average time (ms) to complete a process: ", completed * 1e-9)
```

The printed results (without annoying "Turn: xxx")

Average time (ms) to start a process:  47.2123976

Average time (ms) to complete a process:  47.2141487

Code 2

```
import subprocess
from time import perf_counter_ns 

started = 0
completed = 0

def call(): 
    process = subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "/c", "dir"],
                                                stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                                stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                                universal_newlines=True)

    process.wait()


for i in range(0, 1000):
    if (i % 20 == 0):
        print("Turn ", i)
    start = perf_counter_ns()
    call()
    started += (perf_counter_ns() - start)
    completed += (perf_counter_ns() - start)

print("Average time (ms) to start a process: ", started * 1e-9)
print("Average time (ms) to complete a process: ", completed * 1e-9)
```

The printed results (without annoying "Turn: xxx")

Average time (ms) to start a process:  5.566161500000001

Average time (ms) to complete a process:  5.5675167000000005

Now, this is a big difference, I know these are not the same commands, 1 uses the os and one is interpreting, but why is the interpretation so much slower?
Does anyone has an idea why is it so slow and is there any way to make it faster?
I have searched and found out pypy, *which should accelerate performances*, but it doesn't do the trick as much as I wanted. I know this is possible to make it faster (or at least was with Python 2.7) because I used to use a script which did that. Didn't write the code of that script, so I cant tell why its working there, the only clue I found out was that it used psyco.

**So my questions are:**

1. Shouldn't Python call node interpreter with the command `console.log("hello")` faster than the results I have achieved? (my computer is fine, its not that)
2. Is there anyway to improve the performances of calling interpreters/compilers via subprocesses like node or java (using subprocesses or any other module)

Thanks :)

Comment: Starting up a new language interpreter is not all that fast, in general. And really, on Windows, subprocesses _in general_ are slower than they are on many other operating systems in the first place.

Comment: Anyhow, we can't talk about what "should be" on a system we haven't seen and had a chance to inspect configuration on. Maybe you have an antivirus intercepting process startup calls (except for known-good processes like `cmd`) and scanning the target before letting those executables start up, for example -- it's a fairly common practice.

Comment: One would also want to look at how many shared libraries are used by `node`, how long it takes to link and load them, etc.

Comment: ...anyhow, if you want to be able to start up lots of subprocesses using node as an interpreter quickly, have one _parent_ process running under `node` that your Python interpreter dispatches requests to; have that parent process be responsible for forking off other JavaScript code as/when necessary.

Comment: (You'll notice that none of my comments above are talking about Python-specific factors; that's because _in general_, the factors impacting process startup _aren't_ specific to what the parent is).

Comment: « 1 uses the os and one is interpreting » this is not true. Both are interpreters; one is big, contains many features (node) and can do many things by itself, the other is rudimentary (cmd), has few internal commands and relies on many external commands (other processes) to do something useful. Many programs are shipped with the OS (cmd for example), but they are similar to any other programs (they run in userland).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the comments, I will have a look at what you said and hope for the best :)

Answer (score 0):

so after some more research I have found out why the code I saw was working well and mine did not.

As Charles Duffy said, there is opening many subprocesses is heavy.
The solution in the code was to use a thread to launch 1 subprocess, which will just receive many inputs instead of calling the same subprocess many times. Silly me... Stupid simple, Thank you for your help!